# How to retrieve text from dynamic label and display it to message box using dynamic button?

Tags: vb.net

I have these codes retrieving data from mysql database and display it into the dynamic panels, labels, and buttons. The problem is I don't know how to retrieve those texts from labels(lblProductName) to display it into message box when clicking the dynamic buttons(btnAddto). TIA!

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Module mdlMenu
Dim Cpanel As Panel
Dim lblProductName As Label
Dim btnAddto As Button
Dim count As Integer

Public Sub LoadMenu()
    Try
        SQLConnection()
        With sqlcom
            .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct"
            .Connection = sqlconn
        End With
        Dim datareader As MySqlDataReader = sqlcom.ExecuteReader
        Do While datareader.Read()
            Cpanel = New Panel()
            With frmMenu

                count = .TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)().ToList().Count
                Cpanel.Location = New Point(10, (25 * count) * 7)
                Cpanel.Size = New Size(450, 160)
                Cpanel.Name = "Cpanel" & count
                Cpanel.AutoScroll = True
                Cpanel.BackColor = Color.White
                .TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Cpanel)

                lblProductName = New Label()
                lblProductName.Location = New Point(165, 10)
                lblProductName.AutoSize = True
                lblProductName.Name = "lblProd" & count
                lblProductName.Text = datareader.Item("ProductName").ToString & count
                lblProductName.Font = New Font(lblProductName.Font.FontFamily, 14, FontStyle.Bold)
                Cpanel.Controls.Add(lblProductName)

                btnAddto = New Button()
                btnAddto.Location = New Point(180, 115)
                btnAddto.Size = New Size(80, 40)
                btnAddto.Name = count
                btnAddto.Text = count
                btnAddto.Tag = count.ToString
                btnAddto.Font = New Font(btnAddto.Font.FontFamily, 10, FontStyle.Bold)
                AddHandler btnAddto.Click, AddressOf btnAddto_Click
                Cpanel.Controls.Add(btnAddto)
                count += 1
          End With
      Loop
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        sqlconn.Close()
        sqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of concepts here:

1. How to reference a dynamic control
2. How to bind an event to a dynamic control

Regarding number 1 on how to reference a dynamic control, it looks like you are declaring a form level variable and setting the value. So you should be able to reference `lblProductName` after it is set in the `LoadMenu` method. However, if you did not want to create a form level variable, you could simply use the Controls.Find method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)).

Regarding number 2 on how to bind an event to a dynamic control, you would use the AddHandler statement ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement)), which it looks like you are already doing here:

```vb
AddHandler btnAddto.Click, AddressOf btnAddto_Click
```

So what would the `btnAddto_Click` method look like putting it all together?

```vb
Private Sub btnAddto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim count = If(button.Tag IsNot Nothing, button.Tag.ToString(), String.Empty)
    Dim labels = Controls.Find("lblProd" & count, True)
    If (labels.Length > 0) Then
        Dim label = labels(0)
        MessageBox.Show(label.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I put that event handler but I got an error here at controls
`Dim label = Controls.Find("lblProd" & count, True)`
I already tried putting the name of the form but with no luck

Comment: @Mcgreg - You need to do some debugging here. Setup a breakpoint and see if the control exists.

Comment: I got this new error that says  "Text is not a member of 'Control()'"
I tried everything but I can't fix it with my just knowledge

Comment: @Mcgreg - You're correct. This is because Controls.Find returns an array of Control. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Woah, it works really great. There is minor typo error on your update but doesn't matter it really works. Thanks a lot!